# Table to Table works differently when implemented in Jupiter Notebook and ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, table, jupyter-notebook

I tried to import a lot of tables from geodatabase to .csv to later work with them. I encountered strange values and decided to do it manually for one table through the ArcMap interface. Everything went alright there. I then copied the tool as a Python snippet, ran it in Jupiter and got the same (wrong) values as the first time.

To clarify: I run the same code in ArcMap and Jupiter and get different results

```
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(in_rows="mean_1312", out_path="C:/.../Pre And Tmp", out_name="tmp_mean_1312.csv")
```

Strangely, not all columns are different between these two versions.

Result from Arcmap:
[image: Result from ArcMap]

Result from Jupiter:
[image: Result from Jupiter]

Comment: What are the data types of your fields along with their units and the CRS of your layer?

Comment: Do you view second table in ArcGis?

Comment: Yes, but when exported manually, the values are the same. I changed the screenshot not to confuse.

Comment: I encountered massive problem using CSV in ArcGis. Workflow was to use pandas for statistics, output to abc.csv, table to database table of user choice. I found ArcGis using values from CSV created weeks ago. In Excel results were fine.  I am using random CSV now and it works. Also I suggest changing regional settings to dot being decimal separator.

Comment: Data type of the original raster is FLOAT32  and coordinate system is GCS_WGS_1984 if I understand correctly what CRS means. Does it matter? I thought the original layer has nothing to do with it, as the problem arises only when exporting already calculated table.

Comment: @FelixIP what do you mean by random CSV?

Comment: Randomly generated name at every run.

Comment: What happens when you run the same code both ways?  What is the exact code that you ran?

Comment: @PolyGeo clarified in the post

Comment: What rows in "mean_1312" (which I'm assuming must be a table view) are selected when you run that line of code in both environments?  Unless they have the same values for MEAN then you would not expect the CSV converted from them to.  Try printing their values of MEAN before you try to convert the table.